# Parse error return from HTTP catch - Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have achieved to get the value of the API error return via catch in my HTTP Request. My problem now is how can I get the return value of the HTTP catch in my component when I call the service.

This is my code in my HTTP service:

```
login(username,password){
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');

        return this.http.post(this.configEnvironment.url() + "oauth/access_token",
            JSON.stringify(
                {
                    username: username,
                    password: password,
                    grant_type: "password",
                    client_id: "xxxx",
                    client_secret: "xxxxx"
                }
            ),
            { headers }
        )
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch((err:Response) => {
            let details = err.json();
            return Observable.throw(new Error(details));
         });

     }
```

This is my code in my login.component:

```
this.loginService.login(this.model.username,this.model.password)
            .subscribe(
                data => console.log("data"),
                error => {
                   console.log(error);
                },
                ()  =>  console.log("Finished")
            );
```

and in the chrome developer tools this is the return of the console.log:

```
Error: [object Object](…)
```

But the actual return of the http service catch is this:
{ "error":"invalid_credentials","error_description": "invalid credentials" }
and this is I want to get in the login.component

Comment: I don't understand. What you get in the console is not what you want? What would you want instead?

Comment: The actual return of the service is this:
{"error":"invalid_credentials","error_description": "invalid credentials"

and this i I want to get in the component

Comment: try `error.error_description` in the component.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `.catch()`, change:

```
return Observable.throw(new Error(details));
```

to:

```
return Observable.throw(details);
```